# Cast JSON AnyObject to Double (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, casting

I want to cast a AnyObject from a JSON into a Double in Swift.

`let value = Double(jsonResult["counter"])` does not work

`let value = jsonResult["counter"] as? Double` does not work

`let value = jsonResult["counter"] as! Double` does not work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Numbers in dictionaries(/from JSON) are usually [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html). You can use `(jsonResult["counter"] as? NSNumber).doubleValue`. (The Double type itself is not a class, so it can't be AnyObject.)

---

**Edit:** It sounds like the server is returning your data [as a string](http://json.org/), like `{"counter": "1234"}`.

In that case, you can take advantage of the NSString method called `doubleValue` which parses the string (or you can use `integerValue`):

```
if let counter = (parseJSON["counter"] as? NSString)?.doubleValue {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I'm using <code>   let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)</code> so all my jsonResults Values are AnyObjects.

Comment: Correct — and NSJSONSerialization will produce NSNumbers. You need to convert them to Double or Int or whatever you like. In Swift 2, at least, you can say `as? Double` and it works fine. This may not work in Swift 1.

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039421/using-returned-json-status-in-an-if-statement-checking-iap-auto-renew-receipt

Comment: let value = jsonResult["counter"] as? Double returns NIL. But converting into a string is working. let value = jsonResult["counter"] as! Double. So why is casting to a string successful and casting to a Double returns NIL? Casting to NSNumber also resturns a NIL let value = jsonResult["counter"] as? NSNumber

Comment: @Robert: it depends on your JSON data. If the number is being returned from the server as a string (like `{"counter": "1234"}`), then you'll have a String. If it's a numeric value (like `{"counter": 1234}`) then you can use Double or Int.

Comment: The servers responses a string: {"counter": "1234"}