# Using Returned JSON Status in an if statement (Checking IAP Auto Renew Receipt )

Tags: json, swift, in-app-purchase

Im want to check the current subscription status of an Auto Renew In App purchase.  Im getting the receipt data via JSON, im after some advice on how to use/query the returned data

```
if let parseJSON = json {
                        println("Recipt \(parseJSON)")

                    }
```

Returns

```
Recipt {
    environment = Sandbox;
    status = 21004;
}
```

Whilst I know this wouldn't compile, I want to to do is something along the lines of an if statement like:

```
if parseJSON contains status = 21004 {

                           //Do something

                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider something like

```
if parseJSON["status"] as? Int == 21004 {
    // do something
}
```

This works because `as? Int` will automatically convert a NSNumber to a Swift integer, and because there is a version of `==` that accepts optional arguments.

```
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). It will be:

```
let parseJSON = JSON(data: json)
if parseJSON["status"] == "21004" {
//do something
}
```

If it not working, try to write parseJSON["status"].**stringValue**